# $\mathbb{R}_*$ Notation

Tags: matrices, notation, dual-cone

What does the notation $\mathbb{R}_*$ denote? I am seeing it used for showing domain of matrices, $M\in \mathbb{R}_*^{a \times b}$, which is different from $N \in \mathbb{R}^{a \times b}$. But I do not get what it means.

Comment: Where did you see this notation?

Comment: In a journal paper in mathematical programming and optimization. It can tell something about rank of the matrix, manifold, etc. But the notation is not introduced in the paper. Since other notations are introduced, this should be a common one that I am not aware of.

Comment: Or perhaps a dual space.

Answer (score 1):

It seems likely to me that this means one of

1. $a\times b$ matrices with real values that are not all $0$, or
2. $a\times b$ matrices with nonzero real values, or
3. $a\times b$ matrices with values that are all either real or $\pm \infty$.

Hopefully one of these seems more likely than the others to you.

Comment: It seems to me now more that it has something to do with duality.

Comment: But what does it mean that a matrix is in dual space of $\mathbb R ^{a \times b}$?